# Active online student resources for learning Mathematica

Tags: support

Long time math lover; first time Mathematica user.

I've really enjoy learning more about MMA (love the cloud!). But to expand my knowledge of the language at a level more appropriate to my skill I wondering if anyone knew of a more active student community online? Where simpler questions are perhaps more appropriate? Thanks,

Comment: Have you seen [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com)?

Comment: Yes. I probably should have included that. I've looked at the wf community and mathematica subreddit.  They're workable but responses are way too slow to compliment the speed of programming. I plan to post my project to the wf education community though.

Comment: You can also try our [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica).

Comment: There used to be a student forum at WRI but WRI when they created the community forum later removed the student forum, and then later then actually also removed the site. So all the posts there and answer are gone. Years of very useful answering and efforts went into it, and all other material there about Mathematica just gone like this. See [this](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/744097) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Chat has been helpful. And perhaps it wouldn't hurt to post in the community.